# SQL Joining Diffrent Size Tables Together With Null Value Replacement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am working on a query for a datatable and I can't seem to get it to display how I want, I don't know if this  is even possible in SQL What I am looking to do is get a query to respond with ideally an extra column of Boolean type.

Currently I can run two queries and they both work perfectly but I can't work out how to join them together bellow is the code from my first query what this does is return beers a user has tried this works fine and as expected and returns as expected.

```
SELECT * 
FROM keg.beer 
JOIN keg.userbeer 
  ON beer.id = userbeer.beer_id 
WHERE userbeer.username_id = 1;
```

The second query is even simpler and is just a select getting the list of beers.

```
SELECT * FROM keg.beer
```

What I want to do is run a query and have it return a list of beers with a Boolean value if the user has tried it or not.

Comment: Whats your desired output..

Comment: The standard list of beers which is an id, name and country with an added true false column.

Comment: @teja probably get really drunk :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys it is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not going to run into too many scenarios for "Desired Results" that can't be produced with plain 'ol SQL. In this case you'll use a CASE statement to determine if the person has tried a beer. You'll also want a LEFT OUTER JOIN so you don't drop records coming from your `beer` table when your filtered `userid` doesn't have a `userbeer` record for that `beer`:

```
 SELECT 
     beer.name, 
     beer.id, 
     beer.country,
     CASE WHEN userbeer.username_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS user_tried_beer_boolean
 FROM keg.beer 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN keg.userbeer 
       ON beer.id = userbeer.beer_id 
      AND userbeer.username_id = 1;
```

As @SeanLange mentioned in the comments here, the restriction of the WHERE statement for the userid would cause records to be dropped that you want in your result set, so we move the restriction of `username_id = 1` to the `ON` portion of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so that the `userbeer` table results are restricted to just that user *before* it's joined to the `beer` table.

Now I need a drink.

Comment: Beat me by a couple seconds!

Comment: Have to move userbeer.username_id = 1 to the join predicate or the left join becomes an inner join. :)

Comment: @MisterPositive actually your answer was 0.5 second before Jnevill

Comment: @SeanLange doh! Forgot that part! I've updated the answer to include that. Thanks!

Comment: LOL I meant adding the is null part

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly you did miss the and in the last part of the left join though.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza editted to include that. If it wasn't for the awesome SO community my code would be forever sloppy and untested.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  b.id,
        b.name,
        CASE WHEN u.username_id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS userdrankbeer
FROM keg.beer b
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM keg.userbeer WHERE username_id = 1 ) u
  ON beer.id = userbeer.beer_id
```

;

Comment: Why the subquery? A standard left join will work just fine.